# Drawing a circle on HTML5 canvas at touch location

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Basically, I'm trying to use JavaScript so when a button is pressed on the page, it will begin listening for the next touch on the canvas. On that touch, a function is triggered which gets the X and Y co-ordinates of the touch and draws a circle there. The circle needs to be labelled as well, so have put in a prompt to get the label. Here is my attempt and a bit of context:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Symptom" onClick="touch_init();">
```

When the above input button is pressed the following is triggered:

```
function touch_init(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mediCanvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", drawSymptomCircle, false);
}

function drawSymptomCircle(event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mediCanvas");

    if (canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var x = new Number();
        var y = new Number();
        var radius = 100;           
        var symptomName=prompt("Please enter the name of your symptom:");

        x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
        y = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;

        x-=canvas.offsetLeft;
        y-=canvas.offsetTop;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,128,255)";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.font = '15pt Calibri';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(symptomName, x, y);

        canvas.removeEventListener("touchstart", drawSymptomCircle, false);
     }
}
```

EDIT: This draws circles actually inside the canvas, not just at 0,0 , but they are not drawn in the right places. Why are they are not in the correct place?

Comment: Your code looks essentially correct to me. When you say that the circles are "not drawn in the right places," what do you mean, exactly? Are they drawn at some offset from the touch location? At random positions? Always in the same, but wrong, position? And, have you logged the values of x and y to the console or used a debugger to make sure they look reasonable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Having in the last few minutes added an alert reporting the co-ordinates, and assuming that the top left corner of the canvas is supposed to be 0,0 (I think that's where origin usually is), the x co-ord is out by roughly 630, and the y by 100.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use clientX/Y instead and use bounding rect to compensate for canvas position:

```
function drawSymptomCircle(event) {

    var canvas = this;  // no need to get canvas element from DOM, this = canvas

    if (canvas.getContext){  // this test should be done once in global, not here :)
        ...

        var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();  // absolute position of canvas
        x = event.targetTouches[0].clientX;       // relative to client win
        y = event.targetTouches[0].clientY;

        x -= rect.left;                           // adjusted to be relative to canvas
        y -= rect.top;

        ...
```

Also obtaining getContext() is something I would recommend you do in global/parent scope. `this` will represent the canvas element as the element is the default context for an event handler.